# Cannot read property '1' of null - Angular 6 Update

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular6

I keep getting this error when trying to upgrade by Angular 5 project to Angular 6 when running `ng update @angular/cli`:

```
Error: Cannot read property '1' of null
Cannot read property '1' of null
```

I'm following the [update guide](https://update.angular.io/) exactly, but not sure why this is happening. Has anyone come across this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the way around this issue is updating the angular-cli manually as `npm install @angular/cli` (without the version) wasn't actually updating the version:

```
npm install @angular/cli@6.0.0
ng update @angular/cli
```

All good now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case I was migrating to v7. This was what I did:

- I manually bumped the version of `@angular/cli` to `7.0.5`
- Ran npm install
- Then ran `ng update @angular/cli --from=1.7.4 --migrate-only` where `1.7.4` was the previous version.